# Observer Design Pattern Issues

Tags: c++, model, observer-pattern, open-closed-principle

I am working on a large project in C++ that will have a graphical user interface. 
The user interface will use some design pattern (MVVM/MVC) that will rely on the observer pattern.

My problem is that I currently have no way of predicting which parts of the Model should be observable. And there are many, many parts.

I find myself being pulled in several directions due to this issue:

1. If I develop back-end classes that do not support notification I will find myself violating the Open-Closed principle.
2. If I do provide support for notification to all Model classes and all of their data members it will have a massive performance cost that is unjustified since only a fraction of this support will actually be needed (even though this fraction is unknown).
3. The same is true if I only provide support for extension by making all non-const methods virtual and accessing these methods through base-pointers. This will also have a cost in readability.

I feel that out of these 3, (1.) is probably the lesser evil.

However, I feel like an ideal solution should actually exists in some language (definitely not C++), but I don't know if it's supported anywhere.

The unicorn solution I was thinking of is something like this: 
Given a class Data, shouldn't it be possible for clients that seek to make Data observable do something like

@MakeObservable(Data)

as a compile time construct. This in turn would make it possible to call addObserver on Data objects and modify all assignments to data members with notifiers. it would also make you pay in performance only for what you get.

So my question is two-fold:

1. Am I right to assume that out of the 3 options I stated, (1.) is the lesser but necessary evil?
2. Does my unicorn solution exist anywhere? being worked on? or would be impossible to implement for some reason?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should try to only ask one question per question. And your question seems to be off-topic for this site. Answers to the first questionis are primarily opinion-based and the second question is asking to recommend or find a tool. Try to rephrase your questions such that they are good on-topic questions.

Comment: I think when it comes to design-related questions, it's impossible to avoid subjectivity in the answers. We can break it down into all kinds of metrics, but at the end of the day, a lot of design choices come down to individual goals and desires, experiences, aesthetics, visions. I think these kinds of subjective questions should be all right. "What is the best programming language?" types aren't very much.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're concerned with the cost of providing a signal/notification for potentially every observable `property` of every object.

Fortunately you're in luck, since storing a general thread-safe notifier with every single property of every object would generally be extremely expensive in any language or system.

Instead of getting all clever and trying to solve this problem at compile-time, which I recommend would shut out some very potentially useful options to a large-scale project (ex: plugins and scripting), I'd suggest thinking about how to make this cheaper at runtime. You want your signals to be stored at a coarser level than the individual properties of an object.

If you store just one with the object that passes along the appropriate data about which property was modified during a property change event to filter which clients to notify, then now we're getting a lot cheaper. We're exchanging some additional branching and larger aggregates for the connected slots, but you get a significantly smaller object in exchange with potentially faster read access, and I'd suggest this is a very valuable exchange in practice.

You can still design your public interface and even the event notification mechanism so that clients work with the system in a way that feels like they're connecting to properties rather than the whole object, perhaps even calling methods in a property (if it's an object/proxy) to connect slots if you need or can afford a back pointer to the object from a property.

If you're not sure, I would err on the side of attaching event slots to properties as well as modifying them as part of the object interface rather than property interface, as you'll have a lot more breathing room to optimize in exchange for a slightly different client aesthetic (one that I really don't think is less convenient so much as just 'different', or at least potentially worth the cost of eliminating a back pointer per property).

That's in the realm of convenience and wrapper-type things. But you don't need to violate the open-closed principle to achieve MVP designs in C++. Don't get crammed into a corner by data representation. You have a lot of flexibility at the public interface level.

### Memory Compaction -- Paying for What We Use

On discovering that efficiency plays an important role here, I'd suggest some basic ways of thinking to help with that.

First, just because an object has some accessor like `something()` does not mean that the associated data has to be stored in that object. It doesn't even have to be stored anywhere until that method is called. If memory is your concern, it can be stored at some level outside.

Most software breaks down into hierarchies of aggregates owning resources. For example, in a 3D software, a vertex is owned by a mesh which is owned by the scene graph which is owned by the application root.

If you want designs where you pay almost no memory cost whatsoever for things that are not being used, then you want to associate the data to the object at a coarser level. If you store it directly in the object, then every object pays for what `something()` returns regardless of whether it is needed. If you store it indirectly in the object with a pointer, then you pay for the pointer to `something()` but not for the full cost of it unless it is used. If you associate it to the owner of the object, then retrieving it has a lookup cost, but one that is not as expensive as associating it to the owner of the owner of the object.

So there's always ways to get something very close to free for things you don't use if you associate at a coarse enough level. At granular levels you mitigate lookup and indirection overhead, at coarse levels you mitigate costs for things you don't use.

### Massive Scale Events

Given massive scalability concerns with millions to billions of elements being processed, and still the desire for potentially some of them to generate events, if you can use an asynchronous design, I'd really recommend it here. You can have a lock-free per-thread event queue to which objects with a single bit flag set generate events. If the bit flag is not set, they don't.

This kind of deferred, async design is useful with such scale since it gives you periodic intervals (or possibly just other threads, though you'd need write locks -- as well as read locks, though writing is what needs to cheap -- in that case) in which to poll and devote full resources to bulk processing the queue while the more time-critical processing can continue without synchronizing with the event/notifier system.

### Basic Example

```
// Interned strings are very useful here for fast lookups
// and reduced redundancy in memory.
// They're basically just indices or pointers to an 
// associative string container (ex: hash or trie).

// Some contextual class for the thread storing things like a handle
// to its event queue, thread-local lock-free memory allocator, 
// possible error codes triggered by functions called in the thread,
// etc. This is optional and can be replaced by thread-local storage 
// or even just globals with an appropriate lock. However, while
// inconvenient, passing this down a thread's callstack is usually 
// the most efficient and reliable, lock-free way.
// There may be times when passing around this contextual parameter
// is too impractical. There TLS helps in those exceptional cases.
class Context;

// Variant is some generic store/get/set anything type. 
// A basic implementation is a void pointer combined with 
// a type code to at least allow runtime checking prior to 
// casting along with deep copying capabilities (functionality
// mapped to the type code). A more sophisticated one is
// abstract and overriden by subtypes like VariantInt
// or VariantT<int>
typedef void EventFunc(Context& ctx, int argc, Variant** argv);

// Your universal object interface. This is purely abstract:
// I recommend a two-tier design here: 
// -- ObjectInterface->Object->YourSubType
// It'll give you room to use a different rep for 
// certain subtypes without affecting ABI.
class ObjectInterface
{
public:
     virtual ~Object() {}

     // Leave it up to the subtype to choose the most
     // efficient rep.
     virtual bool has_events(Context& ctx) const = 0;

     // Connect a slot to the object's signal (or its property 
     // if the event_id matches the property ID, e.g.).
     // Returns a connection handle for th eslot. Note: RAII 
     // is useful here as failing to disconnect can have 
     // grave consequences if the slot is invalidated prior to 
     // the signal.
     virtual int connect(Context& ctx, InternedString event_id, EventFunc func, const Variant& slot_data) = 0;

     // Disconnect the slot from the signal.
     virtual int disconnect(Context& ctx, int slot) = 0;

     // Fetches a property with the specified ID O(n) integral cmps.
     // Recommended: make properties stateless proxies pointing
     // back to the object (more room for backend optimization).
     // Properties can have set<T>/get<T> methods (can build this
     // on top of your Variant if desired, but a bit more overhead
     // if so).
     // If even interned string compares are not fast enough for
     // desired needs, then an alternative, less convenient interface
     // to memoize property indices from an ID might be appropriate in
     // addition to these.
     virtual Property operator[](InternedString prop_id) = 0;

     // Returns the nth property through an index.
     virtual Property operator[](int n) = 0;

     // Returns the number of properties for introspection/reflection.
     virtual int num_properties() const = 0;

     // Set the value of the specified property. This can generate
     // an event with the matching property name to indicate that it
     // changed.
     virtual void set_value(Context& ctx, InternedString prop_id, const Variant& new_value) = 0;

     // Returns the value of the specified property.
     virtual const Variant& value(Context& ctx, InternedString prop_id) = 0;

     // Poor man's RTTI. This can be ignored in favor of dynamic_cast
     // for a COM-like design to retrieve additional interfaces the
     // object supports if RTTI can be allowed for all builds/modes.
     // I use this anyway for higher ABI compatibility with third
     // parties.
     virtual Interface* fetch_interface(Context& ctx, InternedString interface_id) = 0;
};
```

I'll avoid going into the nitty gritty details of the data representation -- the whole point is that it's flexible. What's important is to buy yourself room to change it as needed. Keeping the object abstract, keeping the property as a stateless proxy (with the exception of the backpointer to the object), etc. gives a lot of breathing room to profile and optimize away.

For async event handling, each thread should have a queue associated which can be passed down the call stack through this `Context` handle. When events occur, such as a property change, objects can push events to this queue through it if `has_events() == true`. Likewise, `connect` doesn't necessarily add any state to the object. It can create an associative structure, again through `Context`, which maps the object/event_id to the client. `disconnect` also removes it from that central thread source. Even the act of connecting/disconnecting a slot to/from a signal can be pushed to the event queue for a central, global place to process and make the appropriate associations (again preventing objects without observers from paying any memory cost).

When using this type of design, each thread should have at its entry point an exit handler for the thread which transfers the events pushed to the thread event queue from the thread-local queue to some global queue. This requires a lock but can be done not-too-frequently to avoid heavy contention and to allow each thread to not be slowed down by the event processing during performance-critical areas. Some kind of `thread_yield` kind of function should likewise be provided with such a design which also transfers from the thread-local queue to the global queue for long-lived threads/tasks.

The global queue is processed in a different thread, triggering the appropriate signals to the connected slots. There it can focus on bulk processing the queue when it isn't empty, sleeping/yielding when it is. The whole point of all of this is to aid performance: pushing to a queue is extremely cheap compared to the potential of sending synchronous events every time an object property is modified, and when working with massive scale inputs, this can be a very costly overhead. So simply pushing to a queue allows that thread to avoid spending its time on the event handling, deferring it to another thread.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful reply. I agree it would be much cheaper to implement the notification as one signal per object instead of one signal per property. My problem is that I have many classes in my system and I don't actually know which ones will require notification. Implementing a notification interface for all of them would be too expensive and unjustified (regardless if per object or per property) and not implementing would require violating O/C principle.

Comment: I would start out giving all objects a shared interface, like `OmriObject` which every MVP-compatible object inherits. You can provide the universal aspects of what objects need to provide for MVP, like the notification interface. If you want to avoid paying a heavy cost for notification for objects that don't need it, I'd suggest a lazy strategy. Just store a null pointer with each object, allocate a notification system as needed based on what clients request to do with the object. At this point an object costs 16 bytes on a 64-bit system (two pointers: `vptr` and notification pointer).

Comment: 16 bytes is actually extremely cheap for this kind of MVP-type object with introspection and events and properties and so forth.

Comment: And you can still optimize away 8 of those bytes for the notification pointer and crunch that down. That's not required as part of the interface -- so you could turn it into an external structure associated for objects on demand, exchanging some lookup overhead for compaction, but then objects not using it won't be paying for it at all. Or you can turn that into a 32-bit index into a table of available signals. You have a lot of room to optimize anyway, the only cost you can't is the `vptr` for an abstract interface, but you'll pay that for anything that inherits virtuals.

Comment: Now about this 16-byte overhead, there are times when it becomes somewhat non-trivial. For example. in my system, I work with high-res 3D meshes a lot, sometimes spanning several million polygons. So if I made each individual polygon MVP-compatible by inheriting my universal abstract object for notifications and so forth, that would add 3 million * 16 = 48 megabytes of extra RAM usage and more for the vertices and so forth. So there are sometimes cases where it's not appropriate to make really granular elements MVP-compatible -- but those are implementation details....

Comment: Meanwhile, the containers aggregating those elements can still be MVP compatible. My 3D meshes which store polygons and vertices have properties and event notifications and so forth, just not the individual polygons and vertices themselves. There I think in even the tightest systems, it's crazy to try to make a single mesh vertex/polygon MVP-compatible.

Comment: My application has similar scaling issues as it is a financial system with lots of time series values. That's why I've been looking for a dynamic solution to "attach" objects the ability to make observable on demand.

Comment: @OmriBashari I see -- if you want a truly cost-free "pay for nothing but I use" attachment of this sort rather than like "only pay for a pointer until I attach", I think your best bet is an external data structure associated to objects rather than data stored inside an object. But we still have the virtual pointer we can't get away from unless you want to lose all abstraction/polymorphism (no virtuals allowed).

Comment: If you have those kinds of scalability demands, I think it might be good to forgo a synchronized event/notification system in favor of an event queue. You could scrunch down whether an object should push events to the queue down to a single bit. If the bit is set, it pushes them globally (though you might have a separate one per thread -- details). The reason the queue can help with those kinds of massive inputs is that it gives you a separate process where you can aggregate the events generated from a certain object at intervals, and also more easily multithread it in a separate event pass.

Comment: There you can find all the externally-associated notification clients/slots in this global event queue processor, and notify them accordingly. The separate and global event queue just kind of helps to alleviate that per-object overhead and encourage a more async kind of design.

Comment: I've been working towards the idea of a data warehouse to avoid the aggregation costs of some of the classes and allow for different implementations to a generic interface. I have background in event-driven architectures but I'm not quite sure what you mean by the single-bit event queue idea. Could you provide a simple code example?

Comment: Now I see what you mean. It certainly is generic and flexible. However, if I understand correctly, it implies I have to implement all properties of all classes that might require notification using set_value and value. Is that correct? Aside from writing a lot of code, I don't really like the idea of another call to a function that can't be inlined. Imagine TimeSeriesValue.getValue() having this kind of overhead (or in your domain, Vertex.x() / Vertex.y()).

Comment: On second thought, I suppose the issue isn't really with the getters, more with the setters - these have to be implemented using set_value to signal that a property has changed. Same argument though.

Comment: That was part of the reason I was aiming for a compile-time construct. I would like to pay for calls to property changed events only if I explicitly and externally "mark" a class as observable. The closest thing I can think of in C++ that might achieve that are macros, but I'm wondering if there's a template-based design to solve this.

Comment: @OmriBashari Apologies, I fell asleep! About `set_value<T>`/`get_value<T>` to set/get properties, yes -- normally. But you can always create virtual interfaces for some specific type of object (ex: an Account object) that provide the client with more convenient, type-safe versions (`getName`, `setName`). They would be implemented to use `get_value`/`set_value` behind the hood.

Comment: One thing to note is that C++ isn't the most convenient language for this kind of property and signal handling. It's why Qt added their own MOC preprocessor and extended the language just for things like property and signals and slots constructs that are easier to write. If you are really interested, a lightweight preprocessor of your own that parses files and generates code might be appropriate...

Comment: I would suggest that if you want introspection, signals and slots, properties in C++, the strength is not syntax/convenience but the power to immediately mix in very high-performance code (ex: immediately in response to an event) or within the same object providing properties. It's worth compromising syntax a little bit there. If you're looking to solve this at compile-time, then you can lose those rich runtime possibilities (ex: to add new properties dynamically to an existing object, or work with it through a scripting language or plugin add-on to the system).

Comment: In my case I use a variation of the above with some tweaks and advancements (above is simplified), and it's not the most convenient interface to use for C++. But I mix in embedded LuaJIT on top, and the LuaJIT bindings lets you work with properties as easily as `bar.y = foo.x` instead of `bar["y"] = foo["x"].get<int>();`

Comment: So the combo of scripting provides a nice balance there. When we're targeting productivity, use LuaJIT for its convenience and ease of use and clarity. For performance, C++.

Comment: Now about paying the mem cost for property events only when observers are observing the object/property, you can do that still with the above design. Normally the central `set_value` implementation can just change a value without generating events. It's only when `has_events()` is true that it might push to the thread-local event queue (at which point the global system would notify the observers asynchronously). About processing cost, the only expensive part of setting properties through this central property method is the linear-time lookup of an interned string ID...

Comment: If you provide methods to memoize the property index and turn it into a constant time operation, it becomes about as cheap as setting the nth element of an array with one branching `if` to check if the change should generate an event. Your specific `Object` subtypes like `Account` can also provide a `set_balance` kind of method that is not only a convenient but an optimization detail, avoiding that linear ID lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Templatious library can help you with completely decoupling GUI and domain logic and making flexible/extendable/easy to maintain message systems and notifiers.

However, there's one downside - you need C++11 support for this.

Check out this article [taming qt](http://templatious.org/goodstuff/virtual-packs)
And the example in github: [DecoupledGuiExamples](https://github.com/davidkazlauskas/DecoupledGuiExamples)

So, you probably don't need notifiers on every class, you can just shoot messages from the inside functions and on specific classes where you can make any class send any message you want to GUI.